# Why can't I use the explicit form instead of a magrittr pipe in a call to R's split function?

Tags: r, magrittr

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)

split(mtcars, .$cyl)
```

I'm confused as to why the second line works, but the third line doesn't.

I'm reading http://r4ds.had.co.nz/, which states

[image] 
(http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#combining-multiple-operations-with-the-pipe)

This suggests the second and third lines should be identical, but the third gives the error

> Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...)
>   :    object '.' not found

I got the second line from http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#shortcuts, but I don't remember an explanation of the dot in this code. The author writes:

> Here I’ve used . as a pronoun: it refers to the current list element
>   (in the same way that i referred to the current index in the for
>   loop).

But I don't understand what it means for a list element to be "current" in this context.

Why does the third line give an error when the second line doesn't?

Comment: Good question but you don't have to limit yourself to a single resource. I'm sure r4ds somewhere says to look at package docs, like https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dot has no special meaning to R.  It is the `%>%` that interprets the dot.

Expressed in the usual form of function calls it is running this:

```
"%>%"(mtcars, split(.$cyl))
```

and the rules that `%>%` uses to process its arguments are defined in its help file:

```
help("%>%", "magrittr")
```

Comment: Can you expand on that? What does it mean for %>% to "interpret" the dot? What are the rules for such an "interpretation"?

Comment: dot represents the object to the left of `%>%`

Comment: Dot can be a variable name though. You may want to be careful about the "no meaning to R" statement. `. <- 5; .` will give you 5.